# backbone model saving and callback issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, callback, backbone-model

I just start using Backbone. I have two questions to ask based on the code below.

The first issue is after I fill out the form and click the button, the model object should be created with some default attributes. However, the console.log prints the model with the newest attribute from the form I fill out before I pass the model to the new view object.

The second issue is I can successfully save the data to db, but my success call back function is not being called. could someone help me to answer these questions??

```
var form = document.forms[0];

var RetailerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: ' retailer.php',
    defaults: {
        name: 'company-name',
        address: 'company-address',
        phone: 'company-phone',
        icon: 'http://localhost/icon.png'
    }
});

var RetailerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

});

var RetailerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'retailer',

    template: _.template($('#retailer-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        //this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

        var obj = {
            name: form.name.value,
            address: form.address.value,
            phone: form.phone.value
        };

        this.model.set(obj);
        //why the successful callback does not work????
        this.model.save(null, {success: function(model, response){console.log('successful');}});
    },

    render: function() {
        $('#retailer-list').append(this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));

        return this;
    }
});

var RetailerViews = Backbone.View.extend({

});

$('#submit').click(function(e){
    var retailer_model = new RetailerModel();
    console.log(retailer_model); // this prints out the new changed attributes instead of the default ones, why???
    var retailer_view = new RetailerView({model: retailer_model});
    form.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1 Get the correct state of the model

`console.log(retailer_model)` will not show the models attributes, it'll show the whole model, but `console.log(retailer_model.attributes)` will. Also bear in mind that `console.log` **isn't always on correct**, especially if you modify the object just after you log it this can lead to confusion!

To get the actual current state of the model you should make a shallow or deep copy of it. So rather than `console.log(model)` you could use [underscores clone](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) method for a shallow copy:

`console.log(_(model).clone());`

#### 2 Success Callback on Save

To help there we'd really need to know more about your circumstances. The first thing I'd look for is whether your server is returning the right feedback. Backbone is a system based on REST standards. Are you sure your server is returning the right response code? If you use chrome, open your developer tools and then the network tab to inspect what response you're getting when posting your model. In order for the success callback to be fired the server should return a status of 200 or 201.

Another way to test that is to see whether the error callback is firing :).

Comment: Do let me know what HTTP status your server was returning, I'd like to know what the problem was in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to see your errors, I realized that you missed these things:

1. You should do DOM related things when DOM ready event fired:

```
$(function() { 
    form = document.forms[0];
    $(form).live('submit', function(e){
        // ...
    });
});
```

2. You can use `submit` for forms. It catches also `enter` click within form:

```
$(form).live('submit',function(){
    //...
});
```

3. You should use `return false;` within submit form. It prevents default form data sending to action url.

```
$(form).live('submit', function(e){
    // ...
    return false;
});
```

So, it looks like this. I didn't check success callback, but I hope it will work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var RetailerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: ' retailer.php',
    defaults: {
        name: 'company-name',
        address: 'company-address',
        phone: 'company-phone',
        icon: 'http://localhost/icon.png'
    }
});

var RetailerCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var RetailerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'retailer',

    //template: _.template($('#retailer-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        //this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);

        var obj = {
            name: form.name.value,
            address: form.address.value,
            phone: form.phone.value
        };

        this.model.set(obj);
        //why the successful callback does not work????
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function(model, response){
                console.log('successful');
            }
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        $('#retailer-list').append(this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));
        return this;
    }
});

var RetailerViews = Backbone.View.extend({});
$(function() { // you should do DOM related things when DOM ready event fired
    form = document.forms[0];
    $(form).live('submit', function(e){
        var retailer_model = new RetailerModel();
        console.log(retailer_model);
        var retailer_view = new RetailerView({model: retailer_model});
        form.reset();

        return false; // to prevent form data sending return false
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="#submit">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        <input type="text" name="address"/>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="text" name="phone"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```